# Проблема с лицензией VS 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

После переустановки windows, срок действия бесплатной версии Visual Studio истёк.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас интернет есть на этой машине, почему оне не может скачать лицензию?

Comment: Интернет имеется

Comment: попробуйте все шаги, который здесь советуют, может быть они вам помогут
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41781/visual-studio-2017-community-license-has-expired-a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге пошел по самому простому пути, просто переустановил VS. Спасибо всем пытавшимся мне помочь)

Comment: Иногда помогает смена аккаунтов, в студии, переустанавливать - боль..:)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разблокировать VS Community, вы должны залогиниться с учетной записью майкрософт

1. Заведите учетную запись Microsoft.
2. В блоке **"Все учетные записи"** нажмите "Добавить учетную запись"
3. Залогиньтесь с учетной записью майкрософт
4. Теперь у вас Community лицензирована.

[Зачем логиниться в VS?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/signing-in-to-visual-studio)

Comment: Я же вроде залогинен, просто закрыл персональную инфу